# What does 'get emotionally taken away" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does 'get emotionally taken away" mean?
I found this in a interview to some competition winner.
He won the competition and said,'You can let yourself get emotionally taken away.'
I understand 'emotionally' and 'taken away' separately, but can not get 'emotionally taken away.'

Does it mean like 'too happy to hide your emotion' or 'explode in joy'?
Could you tell me the meaning?

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of someone winning a competition, letting themselves get emotionally taken away would mean enjoying the moment and exploding in joy, putting all your emotions out of yourself, letting the emotions to control you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it completely!

Comment: If this answer satisfies your question, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Oops! I've accepted. Thanks!